# How to input two integer by space BASH?

Tags: bash

Problem: I need to input two vars on BASH by space:
How to split it by space?
On Python i can use function "split":

```
a, b = input().split(" ")
```

Input data:

```
12 14
1
2
3
...
```

I can't read "12" and "14"

I want to use "read":

```
read a
read b
```

or

```
read string
a, b = string.split()
```

I know that in bash split does not works      :(

Comment: What's wrong with `read a b`?

Answer (score 0):

`read` itself splits the line it reads, using the value of `IFS`, to produce as many values as needed for the number of arguments given. The default value of `IFS` will split on arbitrary whitespace.

```
$ read a b <<< "1 2"
$ echo "$a"
1
$ echo "$b"
2
```